# Crafting a Postgresql query that only returns rows that have changed values compared to the previous row that refers to the same object

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say I have the following edit data in a postgresql table (graphics made in excel so I can color code for ease of viewing).

Each row represents an edit to an object and includes the value of the two object attributes after the edit is made.  Edits can be made that do not affect either attribute (pretend there is a 3rd attribute that isn't being shown if you want).

[image]

I want to make a `SELECT` query that only returns edits that represent a change to the two attributes in question.

So, for example, edit_id=11 is of no interest to me, because there was no change in either object_attr.  But I do want to select the `edit_id=10`, because that's when obj_one's `object_attr_2` changed from CCC to BBB.  I also want to select `edit_id=9`, because that's when `obj_two attr_2` changes from XXX -> ZZZ.

The edits highlighted in gold below are the ones I want to select.  (also the lighter yellow, which represent the first edits for the objects, regardless of value)

[image]

How can I craft a query to select these records?  I think it involves using the lag or lead window functions, but I'm having trouble wrapping my head around them.

thank you!

PS here is the contents of the table, if that helps:

```
CREATE TABLE public.edits_demo (
    edit_id integer NOT NULL,
    object_id text,
    edit_date timestamp with time zone,
    object_attr_1 text,
    object_attr_2 text,
    edit_attr text
);

INSERT INTO public.edits_demo (edit_id, object_id, edit_date, object_attr_1, object_attr_2, edit_attr) VALUES (11, 'obj_one', '2020-02-20 00:00:00+00', 'AAA', 'BBB', 'foo');
INSERT INTO public.edits_demo (edit_id, object_id, edit_date, object_attr_1, object_attr_2, edit_attr) VALUES (10, 'obj_one', '2020-02-19 00:00:00+00', 'AAA', 'BBB', 'bar');
INSERT INTO public.edits_demo (edit_id, object_id, edit_date, object_attr_1, object_attr_2, edit_attr) VALUES (9, 'obj_two', '2020-02-18 00:00:00+00', 'QQQ', 'ZZZ', 'irrelevant');
INSERT INTO public.edits_demo (edit_id, object_id, edit_date, object_attr_1, object_attr_2, edit_attr) VALUES (8, 'obj_one', '2020-02-17 00:00:00+00', 'AAA', 'CCC', 'irrelevant');
INSERT INTO public.edits_demo (edit_id, object_id, edit_date, object_attr_1, object_attr_2, edit_attr) VALUES (7, 'obj_two', '2020-02-16 00:00:00+00', 'QQQ', 'XXX', NULL);
INSERT INTO public.edits_demo (edit_id, object_id, edit_date, object_attr_1, object_attr_2, edit_attr) VALUES (6, 'obj_one', '2020-02-15 00:00:00+00', 'AAA', 'CCC', NULL);
INSERT INTO public.edits_demo (edit_id, object_id, edit_date, object_attr_1, object_attr_2, edit_attr) VALUES (5, 'obj_one', '2020-02-14 00:00:00+00', NULL, 'CCC', NULL);
INSERT INTO public.edits_demo (edit_id, object_id, edit_date, object_attr_1, object_attr_2, edit_attr) VALUES (4, 'obj_two', '2020-02-13 00:00:00+00', 'QQQ', 'XXX', NULL);
INSERT INTO public.edits_demo (edit_id, object_id, edit_date, object_attr_1, object_attr_2, edit_attr) VALUES (3, 'obj_two', '2020-02-12 00:00:00+00', 'QQQ', 'XXX', NULL);
INSERT INTO public.edits_demo (edit_id, object_id, edit_date, object_attr_1, object_attr_2, edit_attr) VALUES (2, 'obj_two', '2020-02-11 00:00:00+00', 'QQQ', NULL, NULL);
INSERT INTO public.edits_demo (edit_id, object_id, edit_date, object_attr_1, object_attr_2, edit_attr) VALUES (1, 'obj_two', '2020-02-10 00:00:00+00', 'NNN', NULL, NULL);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
with t as (
    select
        *,
        (object_attr_1, object_attr_2) is distinct from lag((object_attr_1, object_attr_2)) over (partition by object_id order by edit_id) as changed
    from edits_demo)
select * from t where changed;
```

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=bad4e1abaa7f818dbf524bf4693cbcef

Comment: Thank you, this appears to do exactly what I was looking for.  (and thank you @GordonLinoff I wasn't aware of dbfiddle).  This _does_ return the the first edit for an object, even if both attributes are NULL: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=2dead1f2ab88d396b1988a178fb9b94d

Comment: @jacobe It is because `lag((col1, col2))` returns `null` instead of pair of nulls when there is no previous row (learned it today, thanks to you)

Answer (score 2):

This is a slight tweak on Abelisto's answer to address:

> also the lighter yellow, which represent the first edits for the objects, regardless of value

You are allowing values to be `NULL`.  That means that the values could both be `NULL` in the first record -- and Abelisto's answer would not capture this.  So, you need an explicit check for the first row:

```
with ed as (
      select ed.*,
              (object_attr_1, object_attr_2) is distinct from
                  lag((object_attr_1, object_attr_2)) over (partition by object_id order by edit_id) as changed,
             row_number() over (partition by object_id order by edit_id) as seqnum
      from edits_demo ed
     )
select ed.*
from ed
where changed or seqnum = 1
order by edit_id desc;
```

Comment: This does work, but so does Abelisto's answer, actually. See this fiddle that has edits for a new object with NULL attributes: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=2dead1f2ab88d396b1988a178fb9b94d

Comment: Everyday learned something new :) `with t(x,y) as (values(null::text, null::text)) select *, (x,y), lag((x,y)) over() from t;` : first column is the pair of nulls and second column is null at all. I am surprised, really. `select (null::int, null::int) is distinct from null;` PostgreSQL is cool :)